# Why is it sometimes $node->field_name[0], and sometimes $node->field_name['und'][0]?

Tags: entities, theming, nodes

Sorry for the code in the title, I couldn't think of a clearer way to ask it.

I have several nodes of the `location` content type, and a view outputting teasers of those nodes. I want to do some custom stuff in `node--location.tpl.php` to affect the teasers everywhere they're displayed. When I do a simple `dpm($node)` to get at the variables, some field values are not always in the same place.

For instance, I have `field_phone` that just has identically formatted phone numbers. For the first node in this view, that field is structured as `$node->field_phone['und'][0]['safe_value']`. But for the second node, it's simply `$node->field_phone[0]['safe_value']`.

I know that `und` has to do with translations, and perhaps means "undefined". I'm not doing *anything* with translations or localization or languages on the site, so it's not like this node is any different from other nodes that way.

What causes this, and is there a function or something that can help me test for and get at the value easily, or do I have to roll my own?

**EDIT**: Chris Rockwell below points out `field_get_items()`. This seemed to solve my problem on the site I was working on the other day. But now, on a different site, it's failing for exactly the reason I bring up here.

I have a view that outputs three nodes. For some reason, when I `dpm($node)` in the `node--node-type.tpl.php` file, I get *six* variable dumps. The *first* one has `$node->field_link_image['und'][0]`, while all five others — **INCLUDING** the duplicate of this same node — just has `$node->field_link_image[0]`. And now, `field_get_items()` is silently failing and returning false on those last five nodes.

So I go back to my original question: What causes this difference between some node variables and others, and what can I do about it?

Comment: I edited my answer.  I believe you should be using `field_view_value()` and the delta on the `$item` passed to it.

Comment: Also, does `field_link_image` accept multiple values?

Comment: @75th-trombone I have exactly the same problem, did you found the solution?

Comment: @75th-trombone have you used [nodeblock](https://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) module in that particular project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lack of the `'und'`, or `LANGUAGE_NONE` level data seems to indicate that the field has lost the ability to be translated. I've never encountered such a field.

[`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7) as already pointed out is the canonical way to safely retrieve field data. Any fields that don't work with field_get_items should be considered broken.

I would hazard a guess that you either

1. Have a broken contrib module that re-arranges field data and doesn't know better than to sometimes remove the language level.
2. Your field settings have just broken somewhere along the way. Potentially because of a reason similar to above.

Does the problem keep happening on newly created fields?

Can you reproduce on a clean install?

Comment: I have seen this happen, but not in a long time, so I can't point to a culprit.

Comment: All I can really think of then is bringing in the heavy artillery, debug the field API, which is quite a complicated piece of code.

Comment: Over a year later, I finally figured out what this problem is, or at least part of it. It's when I use `dpm()` in node--whatever.tpl.php for a content type used in a view. It's `dpm()` *itself*. When I don't run `dpm()`, all the `$node` instances in the view are correct. When I do, all but the first have the language level stripped out. Crazy.

Comment: Just, wow.. Thanks @75thTrombone for the follow up. I've just debugging this for far too long.

Comment: @75th Trombone IS RIGHT!! The same problem here, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need a combination of [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7) and [`field_view_value()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7).

In your case (I can't test this):

```
$item = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_phone'); // unsafe to print
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_phone', $item[0]);
print $output;
```

EDIT: In the above code, line 2 (`$output = ...`), I added in `$item[0]` because I failed to see that `$item` requires a delta.  This allows for fields which have multiple values to be iterated over and passed through `field_view_value()`.  I believe you are skipping the important step of using `field_view_value()`.

If using the above code (including `field_view_value()`) doesn't solve this, I would need more information; e.g. seeing your node.tpl.php and possibly a content type export.

Comment: I think you have an `$image` that needs to be `$item`, but `field_get_items` is exactly what I needed. Its result has the `safe_value` (not just the `value`), which should be safe to print, right? I don't need `field_view_value` because I want to output the variable directly, not with the `render` function.

Comment: That result would be safe to print, but I'm fairly certain you can not rely on `safe_value` being present. I'd have to do some digging to confirm though. Thanks for mentioning the typo, fixed.

Comment: Well, this seemed to work on the last site I tried it on, but I'm looking at an instance of it failing right now. I'm reopening this question; see my edit above.

Comment: You mention `field_get_items()` in your edit, but not [`field_view_value()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_value/7) - are you using it? `field_view_value()` is a renderable array, so you should be able to get the value directly from that.  Additionally, why would someone down vote the answer that solved the original problem, but doesn't seem to work for the new problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I'm using until I find a better answer. In addition to fixing the language issue, it should also always return a numeric array, so you can be confident in `foreach`ing over the result.

```
function get_field($field, $lang = 'en', $fallback = 'en') {
    $var = FALSE;
    if(!empty($field[$lang])) {
        $var = $field[$lang];
    } elseif(!empty($field[$fallback])) {
        $var = $field[$fallback];
    } elseif(!empty($field['und'])) {
        $var = $field['und'];
    } elseif(!empty($field)) {
        $var = $field;
    }

    if(empty($var)) {
        return false;
    }

    if(!empty($var[0])) {
        return $var;
    } else {
        return array($var);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you take a look at this https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7

this is a safer value to use and will work for any defined language, including no language.

Comment: I don't understand how that helps me or answers my question. It doesn't somehow get me the `und`-free version if I ask for it. `$node->field_location[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['safe_value']` will fail for that second node just as much as `$node->field_location['und'][0]` will.